# Looking for a standard function $y(x)$ when $dx/dy = ay+b$

Tags: integration, derivatives

I am looking for a standard function $y(x)$, for which the following applies:
$dx/dy = ay + b$, with $a$ and $b$ both being constants.

Many thanks in advance!!!

Comment: **HINT:** $\frac{dx}{dy}=ay+b$ implies:$$\int dx=\int (ay+b) dy$$

Comment: Solve for a function $x(y)$, then find an inverse (it won't be unique since $x(y)$ will be a quadratic function of $y$).

Comment: Hi Musafa, thanks for your hints. I must admit I haven't practiced math for a while, could you help me with finding an inverse when x(y) = (1/2)*a*y^2+b*y? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As the two comments suggest, the general solution is 
$$
x  = \frac{a}{2} y^2 + by + c
$$
whence, by the quadratic formula, you have
\begin{align}
y 
&= \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 2a(c-x)}}{\frac{a}{2}}\\
&= \frac{-2b \pm 2\sqrt{b^2 - 2a(c-x)}}{a}
\end{align}
which is really two solutions: When the argument to the square root is zero, i.e.
$$
b^2 =2a(c-x) \\
b^2 - 2ac = 2a x \\
\frac{b^2 - 2ac}{2a} = x
$$ 
you get two separate real solutions starting, each varying as the argument to the sqrt gets positive (which may correspond to $x$ increassing or decreasing, depending on the sign of $a$).